# Are questions about best practices bad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, best-practices

I was looking at asking for some help from the SO community in relation to best practices for ASP.NET MVC. I planned on making it a Community Wiki as well.

But, when I was typing my title, I was told that my question was subjective and would likely be deleted.

Why is this?

Surely, if this was a community wiki question, then it becomes not a question per se, but [a source of good information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow).

So now I'm worried. If this question is indeed subjective, why, if it is going to benefit others by helping them as well? And if I do create it, I don't want it to be closed.

Comment: Are questions about worst practices good?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: Yes! I would favour any discussion that stimulates debate and educates people. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time you use the word "best" it is generally going to hit a "subjective" flag. But if you are discussing best practice, those are generally much more acceptable.

Answer (score 14):

The thing about "best practices" questions is they are often incredibly broad.  ASP.Net MVC is a *huge* topic. Asking for best practices on that general topic is like asking for best practices on stopping global warming. You need to narrow the question to an extremely *specific* scenario.

Comment: I agree with staying away from overly broad discussions. I have no problem with "Given this scenario, what are the best practices?" instead of "What are the best practices in C++?"

Comment: That's the thing. I have no specific scenario and this question probably isn't going to benefit me the most, hence the community wiki flag. Whilst I agree in principal with what you're saying, I decided against asking more specific questions like "best practices for controllers", because I was against asking follow up questions like "best practices for models".

Comment: Even "best practices for controllers" is kinda vague.  The most appropriate procedures in one scenario may completely contradict appropriate procedures in another.

Answer (score 8):

Are "best practices" questions **bad**? Not inherently; questions on *processes* tend to come up fairly often, and while yes, they *are* inherently subjective, there's something to be said for just answering them and getting them out of the way.

<sub><sup>By the way: i must congratulate you on choosing to use the Community Wiki feature. This is a category of questions where that flag *shines*!</sup></sub>

*That said...* You should think *good and hard* before posting a question asking for "best practices".

If that's *really* what you're after - a practice widely-recognized as "best" that you can adopt as your own, then go for it. All too often though, i see people asking for a "best practice" when what they really want to know is:

> "Given **my situation**, what are the available solutions to **my specific problem**, and which one should **I** choose?"

Note the key difference: if you aren't free to make changes, potentially *major*, to what you're doing and how you're doing it, then "industry best" is irrelevant - you just need something you can use *now*. Perhaps it'll happen to be a Best Practice; perhaps it'll merely be the best of a bad set of hacks necessitated by the particular corner you've been painted into. But regardless, the focus has to be on **you**.

Comment: the magic word here is SPECIFIC

Comment: Thankfully, I'm in a position where I can put best practices into... er... practice, major or otherwise. We're always looking at ways where we can improve performance and reuseability; 'quick wins' or otherwise. I'm more interested in coding to standards, be it implementing IoC or something as simple as using camelcase across the board.

Comment: Actually, while I'm thinking about it, why is it necessary that community wiki 'questions' like this have an accepted answer? Surely the 'answer' being upvoted by the community is better/enough.

Comment: @Dan Atkinson: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2208/remove-accepted-answer-feature-for-community-wikis-and-subjective-questions