# If my question turned wiki because it was subjective, should I un-accept the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer, community-wiki, subjective

My [question](https://superuser.com/questions/33165/what-to-choose-www-mysite-com-or-mysite-com) was turned to wiki by the moderators because it was deemed too subjective (the amount of answers would have eventually turned it wiki anyway, but it's important to note it wasn't turned automatically) . I accept this opinion now, although when I asked the question I did not know it was subjective (I even asked in the question itself whether it is subjective or not).

Now I wonder if I should un-accept the answer I accepted, for it to better reflect the "discussion" nature the community seems to attach to the question. What should I do?

Please note this is not a duplicate of other meta feature requests such as "[Remove “accepted answer” feature for community wiki’s and subjective questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2208/remove-accepted-answer-feature-for-community-wikis-and-subjective-questions)", it's a practical question regarding how the site works today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still the one that asked the question. If the answer was helpful to you, why not reward the person that gave it.

If, on the other side, you just accepted an answer to keep your accept rate high, I would undo it. **Edit:** Because, as Diago points out, wiki questions are not included in the accept rate, so it does not matter to you, but you do not give the false impression that the answer was helpful. But of course nobody would accept an answer just to have a great accept rate, would you?

Comment: CW questions does not affect the Accept Rate and are explicitly ignored.

Comment: @Ralph: on SuperUser, where the question is posted, I have 40% acceptance rate, so I'm not sure what you are referring to. This is because for many of my questions I did not receive a satisfactory answers. I think the answer I accepted in the said question was very clear, informative, and provided the information I needed to take a decision (that was to keep the www).

Comment: @Ralph: thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

It's your question. If the accepted answer provides the reason why you would use www as subdomain again, I would keep the check mark.
You've chosen the answer from the discussion which serves your purposes best.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need. Although your question was considered subjective by the community and therefore flipped based on the flags, if there is an answer that is acceptable for you in making a decision it should be accepted as such. However others will be able to edit any of the answers and the questions to make it more relevant over time.

Also note that CW questions do not gain rep in any way, either from accepting or from voting.