# Accepted Answers really immume to daily reputation cap and community wiki mode?

Tags: discussion

In [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq),

> Of course, bounty awards, like all
>   **accepted answers**, are immune to the
>   daily reputation cap and community
>   wiki mode.

I did one answer as community wiki mode after I have reached daily rep cap on SO.

I remembered I didn't gain anything on that, and also I don't see on my recalc stackoverflow.com/reputation.

So, I just want to confirm its not really immune or if I'm missing something?

EDIT: I understood I can't get anything on CW (and that's fine), but when I read FAQ again today, that make me rethink. So my understanding on FAQ is just wrong?

<sub>PS:you could find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154384/regex-find-numbers-between-2000-and-3000/2154401#2154401)</sub>

Comment: You don't get rep for CW answers including accepted answer points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2**: It's not a bug; I found an [official source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/revisiting-the-daily-reputation-cap/) that indeed says the +15 aren't given for CW posts. This should definitely be made clearer in the FAQ.

---

*Previous text:*

You're right, it should be immune. There should be a line

```
 1   2154401 (15)
```

in your rep report. If there isn't, something is wrong.

**Edit**: I just checked my own report, I have found the same thing. I'm pretty sure this is a bug.

Comment: You don't get rep for CW answers including accepted answer points.

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes, I just noticed that, but I'm pretty sure I *should*.

Comment: @balpha: No. You shouldn't.

Comment: @ChrisF, Yes, I understood like that too before, but When I look at FAQ again today, its written like that. So, I am just wondering that something wrong. So the my understanding of FAQ is wrong?

Comment: @dmckee: Do you have a reference? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-whats-it-all-about/5235#5235 doesn't restrict to non-CW, http://stackoverflow.com/faq says otherwise as well, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2208/remove-accepted-answer-feature-for-community-wikis-and-subjective-questions mentions the 15 rep explicitly for CW, and no one complained.

Comment: I'm getting confused now

Comment: @dmckee: Never mind, found one.

Comment: balpha, so we will need some brackets like in programming?, :-)

`Of course, bounty awards, like (all accepted answers, are immune to the daily reputation cap) and community wiki mode.`

Comment: @balpha: My comment was, in any case, normative: I think that the right way is for CW acceptance to generate no rep. Why? Because we use CW to segregate the non-technical, and the soft-n-fluffy. It is a shame for that *real* content that is asked in CW mode, but such is life.